# How to cast LifecycleOwner on Service class?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I want to select data on room database with livedata from service class. How to cast the LifecycleOwner when observe it?

```
repositoryDatabase.getTimeline().observe(this, timelineList -> {
    if (timelineList != null && timelineList.size() >= 10) {
        JSONArray arrayTimeline = new JSONArray();
        for (TimelineEntity timeline : timelineList) {
            JSONObject objectTimeline = new JSONObject();
            try {
                objectTimeline.put("doku", timeline.getIdDokumen());
                objectTimeline.put("entrydate", timeline.getEntryDate());
                objectTimeline.put("lat", timeline.getLat());
                objectTimeline.put("lng", timeline.getLng());

                arrayTimeline.put(objectTimeline);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        onUpdateLocation(arrayTimeline.toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `LifecycleService` like this:

Add this dependency to your **app/build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
}
```

Extend your service with `LifecycleService`:

```java
class MyService extends LifecycleService {

    ...
}
```

After that you will be able to observe your `LiveData`.

Answer (score 6):

Add this dependency to your **app/build.gradle** file:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"
```

As mentioned in the [androidx.lifecycle release page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

> Version 2.2.0 ~~ January 22, 2020 ~~ Important changes since 2.1.0 
>   lifecycle-extensions Artifact Deprecation: With the above deprecation of ViewModelProviders.of(), this release marks the deprecation of the last API in lifecycle-extensions and this artifact should now be considered deprecated in its entirety. We strongly recommend depending on the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need (such as lifecycle-service if you’re using LifecycleService and lifecycle-process if you’re using ProcessLifecycleOwner) rather than lifecycle-extensions as there will not be a future 2.3.0 release of lifecycle-extensions.

Answer (score 1):

add dependency
`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.2.0"`

if you have extended `service()` already you should remove it and extend `LifecycleService()`

Your service should look like this now:

```kotlin
class MyService() : LifecycleService() {
    //CODE
}
```